# How to send query in React Router properly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga, react-router-redux

I am sorry if this question has already been asked or does not contribute to the community but I am stuck at sending query string in a URL in React Router.

My client wants to have friendly URL, which should consist of the category name and part catalogue number, i.e.

`http://localhost:8000/parts/alternators-11.2824`.

Right now I redirect to a part show page this way.

```
this.props.changeRoute(`/${subdomain}/parts/${category}-${partId}`)
```

Brief explanation:

- `subdomian` could be 'en' or 'de', or 'fr' depending on the language
- `category` is the category name the part belongs to
- `partId` is the part ID in DB.

So I end up having this URL:

`http://localhost:8000/parts/alternators-1234`

however the url should consist of the catalogue number, not the part ID from DB, like this:

`http://localhost:8000/parts/alternators-11.2824`

This won't suit me because then there is a Saga middleware that fetches the part from API and it needs the actual ID from DB on the backend so it won't find the part by the catalogue number.

The saga ajax request looks like this:

```
export function* getPart(action) {
  const authOptions = yield call(authorizationHeader);
  const location = action.location;
  const url = location ? `${API_URL}/parts/${partIdFromUrl(location)}` : '';
  const partResponse = yield call(request, url, authOptions);
  if (!partResponse.err) {
    const response = normalize(partResponse.data.part, part);
    yield put(partLoaded(response.entities));
  } else {
    yield put(partLoadingError(partResponse.err));
  }
}

export function partIdFromUrl(location) {
  const partDataIndex = 3;
  const partIdIndex = 2;
  const pathnameArray = location.pathname.split('/');
  const partData = pathnameArray[partDataIndex].split('-');
  return partData[partIdIndex];
}
```

So I am pulling the part ID from the URL by parsing the string.

I am not sure how `this.props.changeRoute` is defined, I wasn't able to find a definition of this function so I am guessing it's defined in React Router core library somewhere. I've tried passing additional parameter, like so:

```
this.props.changeRoute(`/${subdomain}/parts/${category}-${partId}`, {query: {partId: partId }})
```

but that didn't work.

I am using React, React Router, Redux and redux-saga middleware in the project. I'm quite new to the project as I've taken in over by someone else and I don't quite understand everything yet.

Is there a way to pass additional query parameter, so that later I can make calls to the API by ID?

Comment: have you tried, `history.location.push(" ")`

Comment: have you tried, `this.props.history.push('/', {
  data: this.props.data.filter(f => f.data=== data)
})`

Comment: I don't have history in props. It says 'undefined'

Comment: I think it's not possible to achieve what I want because in case a user enters the URL containing the catalogue number I won't have the ID from DB because the browser history will be empty. I could search by a catalogue number on the backend but some parts don't have a catalogue number so a part without a catalogue number will not show up.